# AWS Rekognition - How to index multiple images belonging to the same face?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

This document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/recommendations-facial-input-images.html recommends indexing 5 faces of a person straight-on.

But indexFaces takes 1 image at a time.

After indexing first image, when indexing the second image, how do I tell rekognition that it belongs to the same person?

How do I tell rekognition that these 5 images belong to the same person?

Comment: Hi @Jumpa, did you get an answer for this question ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Rekognition: Add extra faces of same person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043322/aws-rekognition-add-extra-faces-of-same-person)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/add-faces-to-collection-procedure.html)

> To associate faces with an image, specify an image ID in the ExternalImageId request parameter. The image ID can be the file name or another ID that you create.

Basically you can upload multiple faces of the same person and give them the **same** ExternalImageId, this way all those images "point" to the same person