# AWS Rekognition: Add extra faces of same person

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I can manage to add an image to AWS Rekognition Collection using the IndexFacesRequest.

However, to improve accuracy I would like to add more images of the same user. How do I let the request know it is the same user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rekognition does not allow you to provide multiple face images for a single face ID. But you can upload multiple faces of the same person and give them the same ExternalImageId. That's the ID that you typically use to correlate a face match to your person database. When your app later presents a face for matching, Rekognition will return zero or more face matches.

Comment: Ok thank you. That is what I did but I felt that such an approach will reduce time performance. Appreciate the solution.