# Amazon Rekognition: How to compare face from one image to multiple images in batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am using amazon recognition to create an API to compare faces. The input or source image would be a single one whereas for the target images I have a collection of images (let's say database). How can I compare a face from a single image to faces from multiple images in batch?

Comment: take a look at this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043322/aws-rekognition-add-extra-faces-of-same-person

Answer (score 2):

You should:

- Create a Face Collection using `CreateCollection()`
- Add faces to the Face Collection using `IndexFaces()`
- Compare a picture against the Face Collection using `SearchFacesByImage()`

From [SearchFacesByImage - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html):

> For a given input image, first detects the largest face in the image, and then searches the specified collection for matching faces. The operation compares the features of the input face with faces in the specified collection.
>
> To search for all faces in an input image, you might first call the `IndexFaces` operation, and then use the face IDs returned in subsequent calls to the `SearchFaces` operation.
>
> You can also call the `DetectFaces` operation and use the bounding boxes in the response to make face crops, which then you can pass in to the `SearchFacesByImage` operation.